# I can't click menu item toolbar to delete all movie in list

Tags: android, toolbar

I am stucking this problem. I would to click item menu action_delete to delete all movie in Movie List. But I can't do this, even Whne I click item action_delete it can't show Toask Nofitication

This is my code

```
public class FavoriteFragment extends Fragment {
private RecyclerView rcv_fav;
private AdapterFavorite adapterFavorite;
private MovieViewModel movieViewModel;
private List<Detail> listItem;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private Menu menu;
private MenuItem deleteItem;
private ConstraintLayout layout;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favourite, container, false);
    toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_fav);
    rcv_fav = view.findViewById(R.id.rcv_favorite);
    layout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_main_activity);
    movieViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, new ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory(getActivity().getApplication())).get(MovieViewModel.class);
    adapterFavorite = new AdapterFavorite(getContext());
    movieViewModel.getAllMovies().observe(this, new Observer<List<Detail>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(List<Detail> details) {
            adapterFavorite.setFavMovie(details);
            listItem = details;
            rcv_fav.setAdapter(adapterFavorite);
            adapterFavorite.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    initView();
    swipe();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

private void initView() {
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
    rcv_fav.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    rcv_fav.setHasFixedSize(true);
    toolbar.setTitle("Favorite List");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_favorite, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_delete) {
        movieViewModel.deleteAllMovies();
        adapterFavorite.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Delete All Movies", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I was trying to figure out, but I can't
Please help me fix this issue, thanks a lot!

Comment: are you shure that you are inflating proper `Menu`? `R.menu.menu_favorite` contains `action_delete` item?

Answer (score 1):

Inside initView() method add this line,

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. but if Fragment I find to this add setSupportActionBar(toolbar) ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);